# Returning a hash from a subprocess in Ruby using IO.popen

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, io, popen

I'm using IO.popen("cmd") in my Ruby script to run an Ironruby subroutine. In my Ironruby script, I am getting some data and storing it in a hash. In my Ruby script, I then use x=IO.popen("Iron ruby script") to retrieve the hash. Problem is, I can't seem to get the hash to show up in my Ruby script. I've tried x.gets, x.read, etc etc.

What would be the best way to get the hash from this pipe using IO.popen?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the subproccess:

```
require "yaml"
puts YAML.dump(theHash)
```

In the parent:

```
require "yaml"
x=IO.popen(...)
theHash=YAML.load(x.read)
```

Comment: Marshall#dump and Marshal#load is two orders of magnitude faster than YAML. `x = {:a=>1,:b=>3.4, :c=>[1,2,3]}; N=1000; Benchmark.bm{|b| b.report{ N.times{Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(x))} }; b.report{ N.times{YAML.load(YAML.dump(x))} } }` =>
       user     system      total        real
   0.010000   0.000000   0.010000 (  0.009638)
   0.440000   0.140000   0.580000 (  0.587589)

Comment: Good point, but I got the idea that this was MRI Ruby to IronRuby. They are fundamentally different, and `Marshal` is defined to be version and implementation dependent. The chance that any two versions of IronRuby and MRI Ruby have the same Marshal format is so low that it can be counted on as imposible.

Comment: Good point back atcha.  I missed the detail that this was crossing ruby implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby ships with dRuby, a distributed object system for Ruby. It may be overkill in this case. Demo:

```
#test1.rb
require 'drb/drb' # in standard lib

the_hash = Hash[:key1,'value1',:key2, 'value2']
DRb.start_service("druby://localhost:8787", the_hash)
DRb.thread.join


#test2.rb
require 'drb/drb'

DRb.start_service
p DRbObject.new_with_uri("druby://localhost:8787")
#=>{:key1=>"value1", :key2=>"value2"}
```